# How can I listen emitted events from BSC network

Tags: web3js, events, ethers.js, bsc, websocket

How can I noticed and get the results of **events** whenever events are emitted on **BSC network**.

I have tried **web3.on()** method, but the **on()** method can work with **WebSocketProvider** and **BSC network** does not support **WebSocketProvider**.

If I can listen events with any other library such as **Ethers.js**, it would be also possible.

Please give me anything which can solve this issue.

Regards!